# primorials and percentage of coprime numbers to it.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Recall that the primorial $P_n$ is the product of the first $n$ primes.

We say that a number $m$ is good if and only if for every $N$ the fraction of numbers in the range $\{1,2,3,\dots, N\}$ that are relatively prime to $m$ is greater than or equal to $\varphi(m)/m$.

Determine all good primorials.

---

Clearly it suffices to check for $N\in \{1,2,3,\dots, m\}$

Comment: You are right, I am so sorry. It should be ok now.

Comment: Your thoughts on this problem are...?

Comment: 210,2310 and 30030 are not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P_n$ be the $n$-th primorial and $p_n$ the $n$-th prime. Then
$$\frac{\varphi(P_n)}{P_n}=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i^{-1}),$$
and the only integer in the set $\{1,\ldots,p_{n+1}-1\}$ coprime to $P_n$ is $1$, so the fraction of integers coprime to $P_n$ in this range is $\frac{1}{p_{n+1}-1}$. I'll leave it to you to verify that 
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i^{-1})>\frac{1}{p_{n+1}-1},$$
for every $n>1$, so the only good primorial is $P_1=2$.